# If given integers a and b where a ≡ 7 (mod 20) and b ≡ −3 (mod 4), determine the integer c by 0 ≤ c ≤ 20 such that c ≡ 2a + b (mod 12)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences-geometry

My initial approach involves transforming the given congruences into linear equations:

a ≡ 7 (mod 20) to a = 20k + 7

b ≡ −3 (mod 4) to b = 4m - 3

then I plug that into the congruence of c getting:

c ≡ 40k + 14 + 4m - 3 (mod 12)

c ≡ 4k + m + 11 (mod 12)

What should I do next?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: You can give any value to $k,m$ if there are no restrictions on $a,b$.

Comment: How $40k+4m$ transforms to $4k+m$ ?

Comment: Are you sure about those numbers? The conditions on $a$ and $b$ do not determine $2a+b \bmod 12$ uniquely.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).